# FancyBox Thumbnail Helper creates new thumbnail at end of thumbnails instead of calling it directly

Tags: triggers, fancybox, gallery, thumbnails

I'm trying to use FancyBox for a gallery of 36 images, but whenever I click on the image to trigger FancyBox, the thumbnail helper does 2 really odd things:

1) loads an extra thumbnail of the image I clicked at the END of the gallery thumbnails

2) the thumbnail helper does not go to clicked image's corresponding thumbnail. instead, it goes to the new thumbnail of that image I made at the end of the gallery.

here is a link to what I have so far: http://lalalichan.com/temp/process_test6.html

At the bottom, you'll see the thumbnails that trigger the images into a display area. the images that appear in that display area are links that then trigger FancyBox.

everything else is working like it's supposed to; i can navigate between my images, i can close out of FancyBox, and when I click on the thumbnail that I want the correct corresponding image appears.

it's just this nuisance that's making an otherwise smooth functionality go to heck.

any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox will generate a thumbnail for each link with the class bound to it so if you have this script

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({});
```

and 6 links with the same class as the selector bound to fancybox like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="{target}" .... etc
```

then fancybox will generate 6 thumbnails ... so far so good.

What is happening in your case, when you load your (demo) page, there are 6 (hidden) links with `class="fancybox"`. Also there is an empty container (`id="content"`) where you display your bigger thumbnails

```
<div style="width: 820px; height: 546px;" id="content"></div>
```

but when you click on any of the (non-fancybox) thumbnails at the bottom of your page, the container with `id="content"` is populated with a 7th link with `class="fancybox"`, duplicating one of your original links, depending on which thumbnail you clicked ... so 7 thumbnails will be generated in fancybox after this action.

Since this link is appended at the end of the pile, it will be placed at the end of the gallery too.

Your are using another plugin (thumbnailScroller), which I believe is adding the extra element to the DOM.

**EDIT : New questions asked:**

*I still don't fully understand how clicking on the scrolling thumbnails would populate the #content div with a seventh link. How could I stop it from doing that while still retaining all the functionality of the scroller?*

Your code needs a bit of tweaks: first, you are duplicating your fancybox custom script ... you just need it once. Second, you just need to load either jquery.fancybox.js or jquery.fancybox.pack.js but not both.

Regarding the functionality you ask, what I would do is:

1: Move the hidden links from the DIV id="load" to DIV id="content"
2: change the css to

```
#content a {
position:absolute;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

3: change this script

```
$(function(){
        $('.image').live('click',function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if ($('#content').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#content').css('visibility','hidden');
                    }
                $('#content').load('#load #'+href,function(){
                    $('#content').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('3000');
                });
        });
        return true;
})
```

into this

```
$(function(){
        $('.image').each(function(i){
            $(this).bind('click', function(){
                $("#content a").css('visibility','hidden').eq(i).css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('3000');
            }); // bind
        }); // each
        return false;
});
```

assuming that the thumbnails are in the same order as the links inside the `DIV` with `id="content"`.

I haven't tested the code but it's pretty much what would do the trick

**EDIT 2**: ***code improved*** Some changes to the css and js

New css:

```
#content a {
position:absolute;
display: none; /* was visibility: hidden; */
}
```

new js: displays the first big thumbnail on page load

```
$(function(){
 $("#content a").eq(0).show();
 $('.image').each(function(i){
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
   $("#content a").hide().eq(i).fadeIn('3000');
  }); // bind
 }); // each
 return false;
});
```

BTW, I wouldn't add inline styles (using the `style` attribute), I would use style sheets instead.

Comment: wow, thanks JFK! i'm really new to javascript and such so bear with me :)
I still don't fully understand how clicking on the scrolling thumbnails would populate the #content div with a seventh link. How could I stop it from doing that while still retaining all the functionality of the scroller?

Comment: !!!! I CANNOT thank you enough dude, this worked wonders and it's so much simpler than what i had going on. i wanted to ask you about this change you made:

$(function(){
        $('.image').each(function(i){
            $(this).bind('click', function(){
                $("#content a").css('visibility','hidden').eq(i).css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('3000');
            }); // bind
        }); // each
        return false;
});

instead of loading a whole link like i was before, this actually just toggles the link's visibility, yes? would you mind explaining that code in more detail?

Comment: Correct. The `.each()` method assigns an index to each thumbnail `.image` and binds them an event (`click`). Then the `.eq(i)` method matches the index (the position) of the link `$("#content a")` with the index of the clicked thumbnail and toggles its visibility.

Comment: If you think this helped you to solve your issue, please don't forget to mark this as the correct answer ;)

Comment: Thanks so much JFK, one last thing. how do you get it such that the first image by default is shown in the display area when the page loads?

Comment: I guess adding this line: `$("#content a").eq(i).css('visibility','visible');` just AFTER the start of the `.each()` method and BEFORE the start of the `.bind()` method would do the trick

Comment: hmmmmm, it's making it such that ALL of the images are visible, not just the first image so i'm getting a stack of images instead. is there a way to target one image specifically instead of the whole group?

EDIT: i think i got it, i just set the variable (i) to (0) and it works. thanks again!

Comment: Let me edit my answer with a new code, it will be easier than adding comments

Comment: too true, how would i give you permission to do that on this site? i'm sorry, i'm really new here, hahahaha

Comment: _how would i give you permission to do that on this site?_ easy, I will send you my invoice and then ask me to do it for you  ;)